# Is the space of finite positive measures Polish for the vague topology?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the space $M(\mathbb{R})$ of locally finite positive Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$ and its subsets $M_s(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq M_b(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq M(\mathbb{R})$ of subprobability measures and finite measures. Equip $M(\mathbb{R})$ with the topology of vague convergence meaning that $\mu_n \to \mu$ iff $\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu$ for all continuous $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support. It is known that $M(\mathbb{R})$ is Polish and $M_s(\mathbb{R})$ is compact. Is $M_b(\mathbb{R})$ Polish as well for the vague topology? It is enough to show that $M_b(\mathbb{R})$ is a $G_\delta$-subset of $M(\mathbb{R})$.

What I know about $M_b(\mathbb{R})$:
From $M_b(\mathbb{R}) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (n M_s(\mathbb{R}))$ we see that $M_b(\mathbb{R})$ is $\sigma$-compact and an $F_\sigma$-subset of $M(\mathbb{R})$. The countable set $D$ of measures of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \delta_{q_k}$ (with $\alpha_k \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and $q_k$ and enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$) is contained in $M_b(\mathbb{R})$ and dense in $M(\mathbb{R})$, whence also dense in $M_b(\mathbb{R})$. Therefore, $M_b(\mathbb{R})$ is separable and metrizable and moreover dense in $M(\mathbb{R})$. Is $M_b(\mathbb{R})$ completely metrizable for the vague topology? Note also that if one equips $M_b(\mathbb{R})$ with the weak topology (i.e. $\mu_n \to \mu$ iff $\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu$ for all bounded continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R})$ then it is known that $M_b(\mathbb{R})$ is indeed Polish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_b(\mathbb{R})$ is not Polish, since it does not satisfy the Baire category theorem.  Indeed, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $nM_s(\mathbb{R})$ is closed and has empty interior (since a basic open set in the vague topology depends on only finitely many functions and then you can freely modify your measure outside the support of all of them).